# If $f$ is onto, and $g$ is bijective, does it follow that $f ◦ g$ must be bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am unsure if this is true, any explanation would be helpful. Thank you,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: try a simple example to see if you can't get any intuition.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman That was going to be my suggestion. Trying simple cases is a good way of untangling ideas like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \lbrace 0 \rbrace $ and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=0 \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad g(x)=x$$